# estimate $f(3.8)-f(3)$ with $f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

We are given $f(x)= \sqrt{x+1}$ and use the Linear Approximation to this function at $a=3$ with $\triangle x = 0.8$ to estimate $f(3.8)-f(3) = \triangle f \approx df$

Can you guys explain each step of the process because I am having a hard time understanding how to use the Linear Approximation equation.

Comment: Perhaps some discussion of what you have done and where you are confused in how the linear approximation applies would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really just an application of linear approximation using Taylor's theorem
$$
f(3.8)\approx f(3)+.8f'(3)\implies f(3.8)-f(3)\approx .8f'(3)
$$
Can you finish the problem? The remaining steps involve computing a derivative and plugging numbers into the argument of your function.

Comment: Ahh thanks so much! The △f in the equation made me confused, you putting it into that format was much more easier to understand, thank you.

Comment: Not a problem. I understand

Answer (score 1):

By the Lagrange formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)  we obtain:
$$\sqrt{1+3.8}-\sqrt{1+3}=\frac{0.8}{2\sqrt{1+(3+0.8\theta)}}<0.2,$$
where $\theta\in(0,1)$.